# Regex replace from a string ( smarty)

Tags: regex, smarty

I'm trying to replace a string with empty space("") after a specific character(colon) ":"

example:`2017 - Alpha Romeo United kingdom : New vehicle (by abc)`

I want out put as "`2017 - Alpha Romeo United kingdom`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it using the following *regex* *(using [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html))* :

```
input        >>  2017 - Alpha Romeo United kingdom : New vehicle (by abc)
regex search >>  (?=:):(.*)
replace with >>  " "
output       >>  2017 - Alpha Romeo United kingdom
```

see [demo / explanation](https://regex101.com/r/dnaq48/3)

**smarty**

```
{
    assign
    var = "articleTitle"
    value = "2017 - Alpha Romeo United kingdom : New vehicle (by abc)"
} {
    $articleTitle | regex_replace: "/(?=:):(.*)/": " "
}
```

Comment: Thanks siam, for some reason its not working in smarty. but the below expression removing \n. {assign var="articleTitle" value="Infertility unlikely to\nbe passed on, experts say."} {$articleTitle|regex_replace:"/[\r\t\n]/":" "}I want something to work in smarty.

Comment: @Developer what you actually trying to replace? the value doesn't even match with the string that you provided in the question

Comment: I want to print everything before colon, no function seems to work in smarty. except the above one I mentioned in comment. my final output for the string i provided should be "2017 - Alpha Romeo United kingdom" using regex_replace function

Comment: @Developer is native php is an option for you?

Comment: its not accepting php, otherwise i would have used simple explode. :( can you use the example above mentioned in my comment to get the output from string

Comment: @Developer check updated answer

Comment: Great siam. working like a charm. thanks a ton. you saved my day :)

Answer (score 1):

```
     private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = "2017 - Alpha Romeo United kingdom : New vehicle (by abc)";
        str = Regex.Replace(str, @":+(.*)", "");
        MessageBox.Show(str);

    }
```